# How to set the file name as a variable under awk in gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

I am using a awk script in gnuplot which is as mentioned below where I want to define the data.dat file name at the start of the gnuplot script.

I tried to put like this
case="data"
and then used the file name as case".dat" inside the below script

```
set `awk 'BEGIN {FS=", *";mycoord1=-10;mycoord2=10}/tick major +[0-9]+/{myfield1=$2;getline;gsub(" ","");print "   arrow from "myfield1","mycoord1" to "myfield1","mycoord2" nohead ; set" }' case".dat" > ARROW.txt ; cat ARROW.txt | tail -n 1  | awk -F';' '/arrow/{print $1;next}1' > ARROW-woSET.txt ; cat ARROW.txt ARROW-woSET.txt`
```

but it is not reading the case".dat" as data.dat.

The error I am getting is

```
awk: cannot open case.dat (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried to define the full file name at the start but still it is not working.

Comment: Is the backquote just before `awk` correct? I don't see a closing one. (If its there, just say so, my eyesight isn't that great ;-) ). I would try to make a simpler test case that proves you can set a value for a variable (`case="data"`) and then see that value expanded by `gnuplot`. I guess I'm surprized you don't need `$case` or `%case%` or somesuch. Good luck.

Comment: AND I would expect (in a shell context), that `awk '{ script here, reference to "$case" here, etc,etc}'` with the single quoting you have used to block variable interpolation, but that doesn't explain how you get `case.dat`, instead of `data.dat`. Did you try using  dbl-quotes on the `awk` script? You can flip your use of dbl-quotes inside with single-quotes. Good luck.

Comment: Dear Sheliter, yes there is backquote in the awk script. I tried to close the awk script with " or ' and then using case."dat",  case.dat, 'case.dat' , case.dat but none of there works me.